# Python List - group by first item, count and sum second item

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list such as this called data

```
 [(4.0, 7.8, u'MNR'),
 (1.0, 6.4, u'MNR'),
 (9.0, 25.2, u'MNR'),
 (8.0, 5.8, u'MNR'),
 (7.0, 177.8, u'MNR'),
 (4.0, 10.0, u'MNR'),
 (2.0, 5.6, u'MNR'),
 (2.0, 29.6, u'MNR'),
 (1.0, 7.4, u'MNR'),
 (2.0, 2.8, u'MNR'),
 (8.0, 3.0, u'MNR'),
 (2.0, 8.4, u'MNR'),
 (3.0, 4.2, u'MNR'),
 (2.0, 11.8, u'MNR')]

pd.Index(data)
MultiIndex(levels=[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0],
```

I know how to get to the data in this way:

```
data[0][0]
4.0
```

I want to iterate through the list and count how many  occurrences of the each of the levels from the first row there are. The output should be something like this with the 2nd column representing the count:

```
1.0  - 2
2.0  - 4
3.0  - 1
```

Then I want to get the sum of the 2nd column:

```
1.0 - 13.8
2.0 - 58.2
3.0 - 4.2
```

Then an average

```
1.0  6.9
2.0  14.55
3.0  4.2
```

I tried doing it with a loop and I tried using zip thinking that if I could zip each of the first two parts of the individual lists into one list I would easily be able to perform operations on those lists:

```
 for index, item in enumerate(data):
 item.count(data[0][0])

 zip(data[-3])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using `pd` and `MultiIndex`, I'm going to assume this is really a `pandas` question.  You can use `groupby` and `agg` to do this in one step ([groupby tutorial](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html)), without iterating one by one:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df.groupby(0)[1].agg(["count", "sum", "mean"])
   count    sum    mean
0                      
1      2   13.8    6.90
2      5   58.2   11.64
3      1    4.2    4.20
4      2   17.8    8.90
7      1  177.8  177.80
8      2    8.8    4.40
9      1   25.2   25.20
```